# how can i set property in build.gradle file to access that property in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using "sourcemuse/GradleMongoPlugin" gradle plugin. It is just for managed instance of Mongo from our gradle build.
port 'RANDOM' running on random port. As per the documentation this port will be available in project.mongo.port.
how can I access this "project.mongo.port "  in Java classes ?

build.gradle

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.sourcemuse.mongo' version '1.0.7'
  }
  mongo {
    port 'RANDOM'
    logging 'console'
   }
```

Ref : https://github.com/sourcemuse/GradleMongoPlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40869506/12833948

As @riccardo.cardin stated, you can autowire `IMongodConfig` and it will provide you the port number - `mongoConfig.net().getPort()`

If that doesn't work, try: `System.getProperty("project.mongo.port")`

If this property is not set, you can try to set it yourself.

In `build.gradle`, something like:

```
System.setProperty("project.mongo.port", project.mongo.port)
```

In Java

```
System.getProperty("project.mongo.port")
```